# Download files are corrupted in IE 11, when user click on Open button of download box

Tags: c#, internet-explorer-11

I am experiencing a problem with one of our website. when the client start a file download IE 11 present a Dialog box to the user, if the user clicks on Open file button before the file is downloaded complete IE says file is moved or corrupted clicking on retry fix this issue.

IE show error message [Click here to see error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwRwR.png)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, which OS you are using for making this test?

When the user clicks the file download link then IE 11 will show below popup.

[image]

The user has a choice to open or save the file. With any selection, IE 11 will download the file.

Generally, If the file is getting downloading then the IE 11 browser will not show the open button. It will show the pause and cancel button.

[image]

So I am not sure, how your client is seeing the open button while file is getting downloading.

If you try to open an incomplete downloaded file then the file will get corrupted.

You can inform your client to open the file after the file gets downloaded successfully.

If I misunderstand anything then try to provide detailed information about the issue. I will again try to check for the issue.

Comment: Is there any progress on this issue? If you had found the solution then please try to post it as an answer and try to mark your own answer as an acceptable answer for this question after 48 hrs, when it is available to mark. If the issue still persists then try to refer the suggestions on the thread and let us know about your status for this issue. We will try to provide further suggestions. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Please see the image, that show what error i am getting

Answer (score 0):

Have the same issue here.
When clicking on the open option, the file download and open the appropriate app, but then the app returns an error that the file is corrupted.
If you save, then open it will open without any issue.
cleared the temp folder and all temp IE files.
Also, reset IE settings.
it did not help.